# Linux specific problem with Write Protected Compact Flash

Tags: removable-storage, hdparm

I am having a version strange problem with a 4GB ATP Industrial Grade Compact Flash Card. I am trying to use it as the boot storage for a ALIX single board PC.

When I insert it into another Linux machine I see:

```
[  421.320908] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     eUSB     Compact Flash    5.06 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  421.331377] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  422.670588] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 7847280 512-byte logical blocks: (4.01 GB/3.74 GiB)
[  422.700420] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[  422.700424] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 77 bd 6f
```

Then when I try any kind of write operation with it, I get:

```
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: Read-only file system
```

Things I have tried so far:

- There doesn't appear to be any kind of physical write-protect switch on it
- I am able reformat it, write files, read them back on a Mac
- I have successfully zeroed the whole card on my Mac (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=10m`)
- I have tried using hdparm to disable read-only mode (`hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb`), which doesn't error but doesn't disable write-protect either.
- I don't have any of these problems with other compact flash cards - but I want to use this one because it is much larger - and should be better because it is industrial grade.

On my main Linux machine, I am using Debian 8 (Jessie) with Linux kernel version 3.16.0-7-amd64.

It feels like there is some kind of soft write-protect lock applied to the compact flash, that only Linux seems to understand.

Does anyone have any other ideas of what to try, or what might be wrong?

Comment: What file system are you using on it? Have you tried unmounting/re-mounting as root?

Comment: I put a FAT32 file system on it using my Mac. I am able to mount/unmount that read-only. But the problem seems to be lower-level than the filesystem or even the partition table.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried other filesystems? What happens if you format it on mac, then try to set up a filesystem on it in Linux?

Comment: If I try and re-partition it on Linux I get: `cfdisk /dev/sdb
cfdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system`

Comment: maybe you can fix this with the quirks mode of the `usb_storage` driver for this specific device, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1088434

Comment: Woohoo, thanks Bodo! Quirks mode of the `usb_storage` driver worked! I was so focused on it being a problem with the Compact Flash, because other cards were working fine. Do you want to do answer the question as a proper Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can fix this with the quirks mode of the usb_storage driver for this specific device, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1088434

If you have to use the quirks mode this probably means that the Compact Flash card's behavior differs from (most) other CF cards.